# How to send int via socket C++ server /Java client

Tags: java, c++, sockets

I have got problem with sending int from Java Client to C++ server. I don't wan't to change code of server (i hear something about htonl). Now sending from client 13928 (0011 0110 0110 1000) i recive on my server 6829568(0110 1000 0011 0110 0000 0000). Is there un Java any function similar to htonl ?

Comment: How do you convert 13928 into bytes on client and how do you convert bytes into 6829568 on server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the code of the server. It's broken.

The problem is that the format the server "understands"  will actually *vary* depending on its CPU architecture. Java is sending the standard network byte order, which is the right thing to do - the server then has to to `ntohl()` to convert that to its internal format. Changing the client code to include assumptions about the server's endianness is a really, really bad idea.

Comment: You don't know that for sure. It's certainly possible, but it's also possible that the server speaks a well-defined protocol that uses little-endian byte ordering.

Comment: @David Schwartz: Well, I was operating under the assumption that the OP's reference to htonl was relevant.

Comment: In these situations, I offload the endian processing to the client side. Server operates/communicates in its native endian. The client does the endian processing, only if it differs from the server...

Answer (score 1):

Just do the math. Use bit shifts, logical AND, and logical OR. For example, to extract the four octets, you can use:

```
x & 0xff
(x >> 8) & 0xff
(x >> 16 ) & 0xff
(x >> 24 ) % 0xff
```

Instead of `>> 8` you can use `/ 256`. Instead of `& 0xff`, you can use `% 256`. Just put the operations together.

Answer (score 0):

look up XDR , this defines the standard that should be used while communication between client and server . if possible copy the int for the cleint in a string and send that string to the server and convert the string to integer over there. this is the most efficient way to send an int.